# WAMP is opening index; localhost disappeared

Tags: wamp

I have `WAMPserver` on my home computer; everything was running well.

But today I am opening `localhost/` in my browser where usually there is a home page with link to **PHP MyAdmin** ....

Today it is opening **localhost/** --> **Index of DIR**  (Index of directories of my www folder)

What have I messed up and how do I get back the WAMPServer homepage when I go to localhost/  and/or what would be a direct URL from localhost to My Admin ?

Only thing I can imagine would be to reinstall WAMP , but it will take time, there are many folders and files in www folder, and e my Databases

Comment: P.S. I was looking for problem: I downloaded a new WAMP exe, and installed in a new separate folder: I found I was missing 2 files from my www folder: Index.php and testmysql.php , I copied those files into my www folder and now I got back my WAMP Homepage; BUT: the new fresh files doesn't read my old databases:( -->> What should I write in those files so they would read my Databases?!

Answer (score 0):

The new install will have registered the Apache and MySQL services (wampapache and wampmysql_ from the folder you installed your second install into.

So we need to uninstall those Apache and MySQL Services and re-install the old Apache and MySQL services.

Go to the Wampmanager icon ( in the system tray )
left click the icon -> Apache -> Service -> Remove Service
left click the icon -> MYSQL -> Service -> Remove Service

Now stop wampmanager ( right click wampmanager -> Exit )

left click the WampServer icon on your desktop or in the Start menu. click Properties. Change `Target` so that wampmanager runs from the original install folder.

Run wampmanager from this changed icon.
left click the icon -> Apache -> Service -> Install Service
left click the icon -> MYSQL -> Service -> Install Service

Now try to run localhost again.

NOTE: You should never put anything in the C:\wamp\www folder or remove anything from it. Always make a folder below c:\wamp\www for example like c:\wamp\www\project1